# Update cart quote items quantity in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.9

I used below controller but cart's product quantity is not updated, didn't understand why this is happening.

```
<?php 

namespace Ves\Productlist\Controller\Cart;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;
class CartUpdate extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $quoteRepository;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
        echo $cartId=$cart->getQuote()->getId();

        $itemId = 499;
        $itemQty = 1;

        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $cartitems = $quote->getItemById($itemId);
        if (!$cartitems) {
        echo 'cart items not found';die;
        }
        $cartitems->setquoteId($cartId);
        $cartitems->setitemId($itemId);
        $cartitems->setQty($itemQty);

        $quoteItems[] = $cartitems;
        $quote->setItems($quoteItems);
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
        $quote->collectTotals();
        die;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edit your code. and add this `$cartitems->save();`

Now please try it :

```
public function execute()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
        echo $cartId=$cart->getQuote()->getId();

        $itemId = 499;
        $itemQty = 1;

        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $cartitems = $quote->getItemById($itemId);
        if (!$cartitems) {
        echo 'cart items not found';die;
        }
        $cartitems->setquoteId($cartId);
        $cartitems->setitemId($itemId);
        $cartitems->setQty($itemQty);
        $cartitems->save();  // Add code
        $quoteItems[] = $cartitems;
        $quote->setItems($quoteItems);        
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
        $quote->collectTotals();
        die;
    }
```

Comment: i added your edited code but still product quantity not updated into the cart.

Comment: added your edited code but still product's quantity not updated.